# How to set Form1.ControlBox=TRUE from Form2

Tags: vba, ms-access

I receive 424 run-time error: "Object required".

```
Form1.ControlBox1 = True
```

sub Form1_Load() is "Public".

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
Forms!Form1.Form.ControlBox = True
```

Comment: Thanks @Toni. Now application stucks for another reason. Says: "Run-time error "2450" Application cannot find form"... Just in case, can you see why? thank you again.

Comment: Try the edited code @3463495.